# Simple Automator Shell Script for image compositing not working

Tags: bash, imagemagick, automator

I've created a folder action so that each time a new png file is dropped into the folder, using imagemagick the new file and an existing .png file inside of the folder are composited and saved as a new file.   Seems fairly simple.  I've tried the script just in terminal and it works but when in automator it doesn't seem to be firing...I'm assuming because of the "f"?

The following is my automator "Run Shell Script" snippet:

```
for f in "$@"
do
   /usr/local/bin/convert BG.png "$f" -composite result.jpg
done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just need to add *where* `BG.png` & `result.jpg` should be.

```sh
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin
where=$(dirname $1)
for f in "$@"
do
   convert ${where}/BG.png "$f" -composite ${where}/result.jpg
done
```

**Update**

If you want the resulting `result.jpg` image to be written to another location; then just update the finial path. Automator passes a couple of environment variables to work with. In this case `HOME` would be your current logged-in user's base path. So if I want the `result.jpg` to automatically be placed on the `Desktop`....

```
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin
where=$(dirname $1)
DESKTOP=${HOME}/Desktop
# `~/Desktop' will also work in this example
for f in "$@"
do
   convert ${where}/BG.png "$f" -composite ${DESKTOP}/result.jpg
done
```

Comment: Thanks so much!  Worked like a charm!

Comment: One quick question, if I wanted to change the destination folder of result.jpg, what would I put in place for ${where}?

Comment: @Chaz Simply update to new path. I'll update the answer

Comment: If i could ask one more stupid question: how would i capture the "$f" file name (minus the extension) to use as the name of the resultant .jpg?  I tried invoking 'basename' unsuccessfully

Comment: Seek `mogrify` & `-path`, or `convert` & `-format`. SO is full of answers demonstrating how to do that. Just be sure to +1 the one that works for you

Answer (score 0):

Maybe offtopic, but why are you always convert BG.png one?

But back to topic: when you use i.e. cron for scheduled script run, verify whether you use full file path. If you run your script from specified directory, it will success; but when cron runs it, $CWD - working directory - will be probably different and no file is processed.

You can for example put the full directory path on commandline and parse it like this:

```
DIR=$1
shift
for f in "$@"; do
    convert BG.png "$DIR/$f" -composite result.jpg
done
```

Comment: Ah...so in viewing the log, it seems that workflow ran unimpeded with  no errors, however the "result.jpg" is nowhere to be found.  Curious, I also had to give the direct path to convert as edited above.

Comment: Yeah...tried that and nothing.  I'll play around with it more.  Seems close.

Comment: Oh, also, to reference your first offtopic question, I have a background that i need consistent with different foreground images that are being automatically put into the folder.